# Does clang or gcc take advantage of referencing restrictions for alias analysis

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, alias, compiler-optimization

I am wondering if the alias analysis passes inside of clang or gcc treat C++ member reference variables differently than pointer variables.  If the compiler could take advantage of some of the more restrictive rules around references this would be a performance based argument for preferring references over pointers.

One way to prove this would be a bit code where changing between a reference and a pointer changed the assembly.

Here is an example of code that might produce a difference:

```
struct FooRef {
  FooRef(int &i) : i_(i) {}
  int &i_;
  int add(int a, int *messWithAliasAnalysis) { *messWithAliasAnalysis= 0; return i_ + a; }
};

struct FooPtr {
  FooPtr(int *i) : i_(i) {}
  int *i_;
  int add(int a, int *messWithAliasAnalysis) { *messWithAliasAnalysis= 0; return *i_ + a; }
};

// These functions are here to force the compiler to compile the add functions.
int foo(FooPtr &fooPtr, int *messWithAliasAnalysis) {
  return fooPtr.add(5, messWithAliasAnalysis);
}

int foo(FooRef &fooRef, int *messWithAliasAnalysis) {
  return fooRef.add(5, messWithAliasAnalysis);
}
```

But with gcc 4.6 it does not.  The same assembly is emitted for both foo functions.

Comment: The comparison would make more sense against an `int* const`. I seem to recall authors admonishing against the use of `const` as an optimization hint however, as compilers are smart enough for it not to matter (barring static storage duration constant objects and the like).

Comment: Dunno. Should ask the developers (check their websites, development lists, the works). Do some experimenting to see if what you want is being done or not. And don't forget to check against the standard that what you want is legal to do for the compiler. Yes, all this work makes sense only if it is extremely performance critical code.

Answer (score 0):

What "restrictive rules around references" do you mean?  In your example:

```
int x;
FooRef r(x);
foo(r, &x);
```

...creates a case where `*messWithAliasAnalysis` and `i_` are the same integer.

Comment: The fact that *i could be changed within FooPtr's lifetime, but the reference to i can not.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific.  I see nothing in this example that would allow the compiler to emit shorter code for the `FooRef` case over the `FooPtr` case.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have standard support for restrict, but many compilers have equivalents which usually work in both C++ and C, such as the GNU Compiler Collection **restrict** and Visual C++ __restrict and __declspec(restrict).

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ft82fed.aspx

Both gcc and VC++ support __restrict in C++ on pointers, but only gcc supports it on references - Because references cannot be reseated without undefined behavior, so compiler can statically determine aliasing.